# Give an equation for the circle with radius 5 centered at (0, 0) in the Euclidian plane.

Tags: trigonometry, discrete-mathematics

Give an equation for the circle with radius 5 centered at (0, 0) in the Euclidian plane.  What is the format the answer should be in?  Is this supposed to be a method in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A circle centred at $(p,q)$ in the plane $\Bbb R^2$ with a positive radius of $r$ has the equation:
$$
(x-p)^2 + (y-q)^2 = r^2
$$

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Would an answer be something like: x^2 + y^2 = 5^2?

Comment: That's correct, good job.